# How to pass flash content to view in play framework 2

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Im trying to pass flash content to a view and it doesnt show up.

```
Ok(  views.html.myView(parameter1,parameter2)  ).flashing("success" -> "hallo")
```

In the template i try to use it like this:

```
@(parameter1: String, parameter2: String)(implicit flash: Flash)

@flash.get("success").map { message =>
   <p class="success">
      @message
   </p>
}
```

Problem is, the flash scope never reaches the view. I have no output on screen. When i debug it, i see that the flash map is empty.

How can i call myView in a way that the flash scope can be processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had struggled with this issue as well. Finally found a decent solution.

The critical point is *flash* being an implicit parameter in the view. That means it needs to be taken by Redirect where the *Flashing* is "packed" along with the result.

**Solution**: Create a new Flash object right away

```
Ok( views.html.myView(parameter1,parameter2) (Flash(Map("success" -> "hallo"))) )
```

The view stands unchanged.

Inspired by "[[2.0.2-scala] Is flashing only intended for redirects?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/oGh3gTmzrLA)" discussion

Answer (score 0):

I guess flashing only works with Redirect, so use Redirect or just pass the parameters with success information strait to the view

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to flash if the response is a 200. Just pass a Map to your view. (You can't pass a Map on a Redirect, so it makes sense that'd you'd want to use a flash there.)